# CFBundleDocumentTypes not working with non-public UTI in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, uti

I want to add ability to open some specific types of audio in my app: *.caf, .aiff, .wav and .mp3*. I've added *'Document Types'* item to the *info.plist* according to the [official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html). Here is a screenshot:
[image]
And the source code of the info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Audio</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.mp3</string>
            <string>public.aiff-audio</string>
            <string>public.aifc-audio</string>
            <string>com.apple.coreaudio-​format</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.waveform-​audio</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

**The problem in question**

The problem is that the app is missing in the "Open in..." dialog for **.caf** and **.wav** files. I guess because UTIs for that files have no `public.` perfix.

Answer (score 0):

some missing extension no problem with that.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
 <array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>Audio</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
    <string>Alternate</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Viewer</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.aiff-audio</string>
        <string>public.aifc-audio</string>
        <string>com.apple.coreaudio-​format</string>
        <string>com.microsoft.waveform-​audio</string>
        <string>public.audio</string>
        <string>public.mp3</string>
        <string>public.mpeg-4-audio</string>
        <string>com.apple.protected-​mpeg-4-audio</string>
        <string>public.aifc-audio</string>
        <string>com.apple.coreaudio-​format</string>
        <string>public.aiff-audio</string>
    </array>
</dict>
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Waveform audio</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.microsoft.waveform-​audio</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: I know that `public.audio` will work for all audio types, but I need only specific formats.

Comment: first try to get access of .caf and .wav which is primary problem. and then remove public.audio and check here re-edited code.